# What does the red symbol with a shield and two swords next to clan members' names mean?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What does the symbol with a shield and two swords next to clan members' names mean if it's red?
I saw what the gray meant and the one with a line under but not the one that is red.

Answer (score 3):

The red simbol means that the player does not want to be in a war. This is a feature of the latest update in which you can choose to be in war (using a green shield) of not beeing in war (using a red one).

this shield can be seen by everybody including the clan leader which, using this information, can now choose who to take in war and who not.

you can change this at your profile screen.

Answer (score 1):

Red shield and swords, means the clan member is opting out of clan wars.  His/her spot will be passed to the next available clan member.

It's a change implemented in the latest patch, you can access your war availability through the "My Profile" screen.

Comment: Actually, that symbol simply communicates that players *preference* for clan wars. The clan leaders are ultimately responsible for selecting who goes to war, and can easily include people who have indicated that they'd like to opt out.